# Uploading to own YouTube account from iOS app

Tags: ios, upload, youtube

The app should be uploading videos from iOS devices directly to our own YouTube account (not user's account).

In every scenario I came across you need an Access Token that you can get only from user logging in through OAuth2 (window popping up). Obviously, we can't give everyone username and password from company account. I was imagining using some key that uniquely identifies the app and YouTube user account to use.

Any solution / pointer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using deprecated Client Login. We still need to figure where to store passwords (either in the client app, or fetch them from backend every time), but that's already a huge progress.

Unfortunately, Google says Client Login will be removed in 2015. We can just hope they'll come up with non-interactive auth method requiring no user interaction by then.

Comment: any solution you found