# Uploading videos from apps google account

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, google-api-objc-client

I want to use Google Data API v3 for uploading video to youtube from apps developer account. I am trying to find out a way to login developer account on users device, but i am unable to find any documentation provide by google related to Objective c. So can any one guide me how i can login with my account on users device so that they can upload videos on youtube from my account.

[Uploading to own YouTube account from iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345153/uploading-to-own-youtube-account-from-ios-app)

Answer (score 0):

You have all the documentation how to use YouTube Data API (v3) [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)

The login documentation   [Login Doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication)

and look at the sample code [Sample Code](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples/YouTubeSample) you will find what you want. ( see `YouTubeSampleWindowController` class).